# doxygen document c++ class templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, doxygen

Im trying to document the following:

```
template <class T, int NDim>
class myClass {

public:
.
.
```

here's the doxygen

```
/*!
 * \class myClass<T, NDim>
 * \brief Defines a class for stuff. 
*/
```

Generation yields:

> myClass Class Reference
>
> Defines a class for stuff.

So i'm missing the template information, but thats not the end of the world since i know that doxygen doesn't deal with templates well. The main problems is the warning during generation:

> myClass.h:2: warning: the name `T' supplied as the argument of the
>   \class, \struct, \union, or \include command is not an input file

How can i resolve this warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIK it's not necessary to specify `\class` explicitly, doxygen should detect the class name automatically, as long you put the documentation immediately before the template class declaration

```
/** << NOTE
 * \brief Defines a class for stuff. 
 * \tparam T Type to work with.
 * \tparam NDim Number of dimensions.
 */
template <class T, int NDim>
class myClass {

public:
.
.
};
```

To specify documentation for template parameters use `\tparam`.

Also note: Usage of `<` and `>` will be interpreted as inline HTML tags by doxygen. Use `\<` and `\>` instead.

Comment: for me, if i remvoe `\class` the html file is not generated for that class

Comment: @ldgorman Strange, I'm using it all the time as shown in my sample. I'm not sure if it's because of how the doxygen comment block is started (I'm using `/**` instead of `/*!`)

Comment: excellent, changing the comment block delimiter to `/**` seems to have fixed it. Thank you